# bind data to grid view in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a data grid view and a button in my ASP.net page.

I'm calling this method on button click event.

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     getlbCat();
 }
```

This is lbCat method

```
 public void getlbCat()
{
    GVDetails.DataSource = new LibraryCatalogueOP().getLibraryCatalogue();
}
```

This is my business layer method

```
public DataTable getLibraryCatalogue()
{
    string quary1 = "EXEC SelectLibraryCatalogue";
    return new DataAccessLayer().executeTable(quary1);
}
```

But when I click the button the grid view doesn't fill with data.

How to solve this ?

I'm using visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call DataBind method of grid

```
public void getlbCat()
{
    GVDetails.DataSource = new LibraryCatalogueOP().getLibraryCatalogue();
    GVDetails.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly myself. Sorry if I wasted your time viewers.
 I have missed the line  GVDetails.DataBind();

```
public void getlbCat()
{
   GVDetails.DataSource = new LibraryCatalogueOP().getLibraryCatalogue();
   GVDetails.DataBind();
}
```